# Best way to output two streams, and add lower thirds keying to one stream?

Tags: video, digital-recording

We are looking to enhance our production with some lower thirds keying on our video.

We currently output a single HD stream and encode it in real time. This output doesn't have any keying because it's application requires it to NOT have this.

A new request that has come in is to have a separate recording that DOES have lower thirds keying for a couple of select applications.

We could add the keying in post production, however this is time consuming and we'd rather not.

*I've attached a diagram of how our system is currently configured.*

I'm wondering what the best way to add lower thirds keying would be if we're doing it in real time on a second stream... and is this possible with our current equipment list?

[image: Video Diagram]

---

My thought on this would be to throw a Mac mini on the second `preview` output and use software to key the output of the Mac back into a second input card on the StreamZHD.

I'm a little nervous in using the built in keying ability as it would require a single operator to be managing ALL of our production.

Comment: Now, why don't you use the AVhs400 keying capability and store that output?

Comment: As I said above `I'm a little nervous in using the built in keying ability as it would require a single operator to be managing ALL of our production.`

Comment: I think you shouldn't, it can take some time for the operator to get used to the 'new' flow of work but it's worth it, specially if you are only working with only one output. However, if you are still nervous about it, I don't think the idea of using a Mac mini is any ideal. I would use a Folsom switcher instead, but the price is too high compared to that of a computer.

Answer (score 1):

Much like your Mac Mini approach, you can set up a PC with a free demo of vMix (http://www.vmix.com.au) and see if it will work for you.

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend to add an optional i/o board (AV-HS04M7 or AV-HS04M1 for external CG) to have simultaneous program output w/o graphics (clean feed) and still have fully functional preview & program outputs. You can use ProPresenter or any template-based CG with key&fill outputs, which is quite simple to control. E.g. [CasparCG](http://www.casparcg.com/). You can even create a special control application for shows, an operator would have to push the only button at desired time.